# Embedding ActiveRecord query, .each do block into AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord, erb

I'm trying to build a dashboard in Rails where the data changes based on a dropdown of cohort names - this will empty any current data in the dashboard and populate it with a new list of students corresponding to that cohort. Going through what I've read in other topics, I changed my immensely poor code and wrote the following within an AJAX request:

```
<% Student.where(cohort_id: Cohort.find_by(name: choice).id).each do |student| %>
    $studentList.append(
      '<a href="/students/<%=student.id%>"><%= student.first_name %> <%= student.last_name%></a>')
<% end %>
```

The AJAX request is currently able to change the text values of headers in the dashboard and is able to empty the content of a student list pre-populated on load, but including these three lines produces an error: Unexpected token %.

I'm working from the assets folder on a .js.erb file, and the scriptlets & expressions seem to work in topics I've researched.

What am I missing? Is there another method I should try to get this to load?

Thanks

EDIT:

So here's what I have in my Instructors Controller (this is meant to be a dashboard for an Instructor to use) and the dash.js.erb file:

```
def cohort
  students = Student.where(cohort_id: Cohort.find_by(name: params[:choice]).id)
  response = []
  students.each do |student|
    response.push({
      id:         student.id,
      first_name: student.first_name,
      last_name:  student.last_name
    })
  end
  render json: response
end
```

Cohort is where I was sending my original JSON request to

```
var $cohortChoice = $('.cohort-choice');
$cohortChoice.on('change', function(){

  var choice = $cohortChoice.val().trim();
  console.log(choice);

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/instructors/dash/cohort",
    data: { choice: choice},
    success: function(response, status, xhr){
      $dashCohort = $('.dash').children().first()
      $dashCohort.text("Cohort: "+choice)
      var $studentList = $('.scroll-down').eq(0)
      $studentList.empty()
      response.forEach(function(student) {
        $studentList.append('<a href="/students/'+student.id+'">'+ student.first_name + ' ' + student.last_name + '</a>')
      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
      console.log(xhr, status, error)
    },
  })
});
```

This is now telling me there's a NoMethodError in InstructorsController, saying that .id won't work on nil. My suspicion is that it's not pulling out params[:choice]

Comment: What is `console.log(choice)` outputting? Also, what is output to your servers console when you add `puts param[:choice]` into your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't recommend embedding database logic into view-specific files. That workload belongs in a controller.

To implement what you're needing as an AJAX call, you'd need something like this in your controller (in this case, I'm assuming your `Students` controller would be the most logical place):

```
def fetch_students
  students = Student.where(cohort_id: Cohort.find_by(name: params[:choice]).id)
  response = []

  students.each do |student|
    response.push({
      id:         student.id,
      first_name: student.first_name,
      last_name:  student.last_name
    })
  end

  render json: response
end
```

And then you could invoke this in your `.js.erb` file like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<%= fetch_students_students_index_path %>",
  type: 'GET',
  data: { choice: choice },
  success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    response.forEach(function(student) {
      $studentList.append('<a href="/students/' + student.id + '">' + student.first_name + ' ' + student.last_name + '</a>')
    });
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr, status, error);
  },
});
```

Don't forget to create the `fetch_students` endpoint in your Router.

Comment: Great answer, except I think the ajax url should be '<%= %>' instead of '#{}'

Comment: Nah, that's actually correct. That's basic string interpolation in Ruby.

Comment: well strings cannot be interpolated inside single quotes anyway. Also, as far as I'm aware you can't execute ruby code within an erb file without <% %>. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've made some edits to the topic and am continuing to work through it. I'm not entirely sure that the AJAX is pulling params[:choice] out, so the method in the controller is trying to find the id of nil.

Comment: @userFriendly oh geez, you're totally right. Sorry, I was working in Slim when I answered this so my mind was totally in Slim-mode, not Erb. I'm updating the answer now. Interesting sidenote: single quoted string interpolation will actually work fine in Slim.

Comment: @Sergey you have to pass in the choice through the AJAX call. Obviously, that'll be totally up to you to implement however you want. In `data: { choice: choice }`, the value that I've got defined as `choice` can be whatever you want.

Comment: @jeffdill2 - Yup I got it working yesterday, thanks!

Comment: @SergeyKolchinskiy great! Glad it's working for you. If my answer worked for you, accepting and upvoting it would be awesome. :-)

Comment: @jeffdill2 - gladly! I can definitely accept it, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote it apparently.

Comment: @SergeyKolchinskiy no worries! Glad everything's working for you.